# Reducing code with the use of Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm beginning to use Handlebars and the architectural pattern Model View ViewModel and I wrote this code :

```
var data = {
        currentPlayer: this._model.currentPlayer,
        line: [
            {
                row:
                [
                    {
                        caseNumber:1,
                        caseValue: this._model.getCaseState(0,0)
                    },
                    {
                        caseNumber:2,
                        caseValue: this._model.getCaseState(0,1)
                    },
                    {
                        caseNumber:3,
                        caseValue: this._model.getCaseState(0,2)
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                row:[
                    {
                        caseNumber:4,
                        caseValue:this._model.getCaseState(1,0)
                    },
                    {
                        caseNumber:5,
                        caseValue:this._model.getCaseState(1,1)
                    },
                    {
                        caseNumber:6,
                        caseValue:this._model.getCaseState(1,2)
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                row:[
                    {
                        caseNumber:7,
                        caseValue:this._model.getCaseState(2,0)
                    },
                    {
                        caseNumber:8,
                        caseValue:this._model.getCaseState(2,1)
                    },
                    {
                        caseNumber:9,
                        caseValue: this._model.getCaseState(2,2)
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
    var htmlContent = this._template(data);
    this._element.html(htmlContent);
```

With the following template :

```
<div>
    <h3>It is to player {{currentPlayer}}</h3>
    <table>
        {{#each line}}
        <tr>
            {{#row}}
            <td data="{{caseNumber}}" class="case{{caseValue}}">{{caseValue}}</td>
            {{/row}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</div>
```

This code works fine but I'm asking if I cannot reduce it. So I tried to use a for loop in the var data but I realized that I can't do this.
My other choice was to use an if in the template like this :

```
{{#each line}}
    <tr>
        {{#row}}
        {{#if caseValue}}
        <td data="{{caseNumber}}" class="case{{caseValue}}">O</td>
        {{else}}
        <td data="{{caseNumber}}" class="case{{caseValue}}">X</td>
        {{/if}}
        {{/row}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

by testing the value of the var `caseValue`. However, as `caseValue` takes the value of `1` or `0` or `undefined`, if the case isn't checked all the cells are filled with a "X".
So, I can't find a compact solution with the aim of :

- At the beginning, all the TD tags are empty.
- Depending on the value of `getCaseState` which returns `0` or `1` fill
  the  cell with an "X" or an "O".

EDIT : I manage the different values of `getCaseState` with this code :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('displayTd', function(data) {
        var result;
        if(data.caseValue === undefined) {
            result = '<td data="' + data.caseNumber + '"></td>';
            return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
        } else if(data.caseValue === 1) {
            result = '<td data="' + data.caseNumber + '" class="case' + data.caseValue + '">X</td>';
            return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
        } else {
            result = '<td data="' + data.caseNumber + '" class="case' + data.caseValue + '">O</td>';
            return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step I would take to reduce the code was the one you alluded to about using loops to construct your data. The data in your `line` object follows a simple pattern, so we can construct with the following code:

```
var numRows = 3;
var numColumns = 3;
var line = [];

for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++) {
    line[rowIndex] = { row: [] };
    for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numColumns; columnIndex++) {
        line[rowIndex].row[columnIndex] = {
            caseNumber: ((rowIndex * numColumns) + columnIndex + 1),
            caseValue: getCaseState(rowIndex, columnIndex)
        };
    }
}
```

*Note that you will have to call `getCaseState` on your existing model object.

Our `data` object then becomes:

```
var data = {
    currentPlayer: this._model.currentPlayer,
    line: line
};
```

As for the conditional within your template, I would recommend creating your own Handlebars helper. Fortunately, Handlebars has an [`isEmpty`](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#utils-isEmpty) utility method that returns true for:

> - Array with length 0
> - falsy values other than 0

This means that we can use this utility method to check if our `caseValue` is `undefined`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getCharacter', function (caseValue) {
    return Handlebars.Utils.isEmpty(caseValue) ? '' : (caseValue === 0 ? 'X' : 'O');
});
```

We then use our new helper in our template in the following way:

```
{{#each row}}
    <td data="{{caseNumber}}" class="case{{caseValue}}">{{getCharacter caseValue}}</td>  
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your BIG help (and to fix my English mistakes ^^). I never thought about that solution for the data construction.  For the conditional within my template I have tried this : [see my edit] but your solution looks better.